# When zooming desktop website above 150% it reverts to mobile responsive mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

When zooming desktop website above 150% it reverts to mobile  responsive mode.
How would i go about to prevent this behavior?

this is the website:
http://betafinance.co.il/

Zoom to 150 percent and you will see what I mean.

thank you

Comment: That is by design. You can see that the page width reduces as you zoom in. Try running `window.innerWidth` in the console as you zoom in.

Comment: but is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: If you want to continue using bootstrap, none that I am aware of. It is actually a good thing in my opinion. Not sure, why you'd want to remove that?!

Answer (score 1):

According to this(great) article:

https://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/media-queries-and-browser-zoom/

**The main problem** is that the website `media-query` uses **fixed units** (px) instead of **elastic** ones (em)

Convert your pixels (the formula is also noted in the link I attached).. That should fix it :)